# ActiveAdmin: Display Parent name in column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

So the basics is that I currently has a self referencing model called categories show below

```
class Category < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :category
    has_many :children, -> { order(:name) }, :dependent => :destroy, :class_name => 'Category'

    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Here is the ActiveAdmin class for Category

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
    permit_params :name, :category_id

    index do
        column :name
        column(:category_id) do |category| 
            category.category_id? ? category.category_id : 'Parent'
        end
        actions
    end
end
```

What I am trying to do is to check if the category is a subcategory, if it is display the parent name, if is not display 'Parent'. I have the code for displaying parent working as you see above.

If I do not use the code block and just use the following:

```
column :category_id
```

Then It will show the parent name. But here is what I see when I use category.category_id inside the codeblock

[image: Category Table displaying numeric for parent category]

Maybe I am missing something but any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out but wanted to share what I found out. When using a self referencing column, you can use model.model to display the parent child relationship. Below was the change I made to make this work:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Category do
    permit_params :name, :category_id

    index do
        column :name
        column "Parent Category", (:category_id) do |category| 
            category.category_id? ? category.category : 'Parent'
        end
        actions
    end
end
```

As you can see, using the category.category in the code block allowed the parent to be displayed. Hope this helps someone in the future.